# git cherry-pick SHA1 ID

Tags: git, git-branch, git-cherry-pick

I am still new to git and I came across this cherry-pick command. Lets say I 
cherry-pick a commit (lets call it CA) from *devel* branch to the *master* 
branch and they now both have different sha1 id if what I interpret is correct.

So my question is, if later I want to check the "differences" between *devel* 
branch and *master* branch using  `git cherry`to find out which commits are 
eventually pushed to *master* and which does not, but since the commits (CA) I 
cherry-picked just now will have a different SHA1 id so when I execute `git 
cherry master devel` what does it tell me? Does it tell me CA is pushed to the 
*master*? Or does it tell me CA is NOT pushed to the *master* since they don't 
share the same SHA1 ID?

Comment: the git cherry manpage ("man git cherry" or "git help cherry") seems to answer your questions directly -- and it's short, there's nothing much on there _but_ relevant answers.

Comment: Yeah I read the man page but I guess I just got confused with how git cherry operates. Does it flush out the commits not merged upstream by comparing each commits ID or by comparing their actual differences?

Answer (score 1):

`git cherry` uses `git patch-id` to compare the commits. Two commits introducing the same change will have the same patch ID, and `git cherry` will say that the change already exists in upstream by prefixing the commit with a hyphen/minus (-) sign.

So in your case `git cherry master devel` would output the commit you cherry-picked prefixed with a hyphen/minus (-), indicating that the change it introduces already exists in master. Commits introducing changes that do not exist in master would be prefixed with a plus sign (+).

This is explained in [man git-cherry](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry.html).